# Android navigation component back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, fragment-backstack

i created a nav graph with fragments fragA->fragB->fragC-fragD->fragE->fragF->fragG. From some push notification user must directly go to fragG with `findNavController().navigate(R.id.fragG)`, and when user tap back button he must go to fragF, but now is back to first fragment of navigation graph because fragB->fragC-fragD->fragE->fragF is not added to back stack. It's possible to add this frag to stack when user navigate to last an press back button? Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link

Comment: in documentation wrote that only start destination is added to back stack, not all fragment till destination

Comment: did you try it out

Comment: Yes, is added only start destination

Answer (score 3):

It's not an official answer but it works as a workaround.

You can create the back stack manually by navigating sequentially.

```
fun openGFromPushNotification(){
   navigate(R.id.fragB)
   navigate(R.id.fragC)
   navigate(R.id.fragD)
   navigate(R.id.fragE)
   navigate(R.id.fragF)
   navigate(R.id.fragG)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me. But it's depressing that this is the best option. You have to be careful to only use destination ids `R.id.fragB`, rather than action ids `R.id.fragA_to_fragB`, or safe args `FragADirections.actionFragAFragmentToFragBFragment()`. Only destination ids will work - the others will throw exceptions like `Navigation X cannot be found from the current destination`.